# Get raw template from Vue.js SSR (Vue3)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm looking for a solution to get the "raw" template from a cue app.
So if I create a Vue.js App with different .vue SF-Components I want to get the "complete" template from the app. But it should include already the vue tags like "v-if", ...

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Thank you!